# How to infer generic type argument of union?

Tags: typescript, generics, union, type-inference

I want to infer generic arguments of a union like in the attached code. What does InferValueTypes should be?

```
interface WithValue<T> {}

interface ValuedNumber extends WithValue<number> {}
interface ValuedString extends WithValue<string> {}

type Valued = ValuedNumber | ValuedString;

type InverValueType<T extends WithValue<any>> = T extends WithValue<infer V>  ? V : never;
type AType = InferValueType<ValuedNumber>; // Will infer `number`

type InferValueTypes<T> = ???;
type ValueTypes = InferValueTypes<Valued>; // Expect to infer `string | number`
```

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to return, as a string, the type out of typescript?

Comment: That is what i see inferred https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ts=3.8.3&ssl=12&ssc=19&pln=12&pc=48#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwGpwDYCuEAPACoB8yA3snAFzKnIC+AUK6JLIiroRABMAcgQC2AI2jIIAD0ggBAZzQYc+IsRBjJUSlTado8JMj5EBAZTBRQAc2lyIC5eixmSi63b1tWYAJ4ADrzqgsgAvKahwtpSAD5R-JZeILYA3OwBwcgAkiAw0O6kQSRMsvJKKm6hxHAg-uSUkWWOzlVq-MSgBVCmlMgA-KbIDCAQAG7QGVkoAILF2ZF5PUUlxO4xEtDkacgA9HsqeHjI3VIABlpbUOfsfiWJRAsQykv5haHP69E7+4cAojJgggwMgwAB7U7vXrnTw2VLIBJXHTnIA

Answer (score 0):

`InferValueTypes` can deal with unions well. I need to be more attentive.